# Angular 7 - Compute dynamically step attribute of input number onChange

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I need to implement an input field of type number where step attribute is computed dynamically.

Initial step = 5 
When reaching 25 change the step to 10

this how my code looks like :

MyTemplate.html :

```
<input step="{{this.step}}" type="number" min="10" formControlName="share" (change)="computeStep()">
```

MyComponent.ts :

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.step = 5;
}
...
computeStep() {
    if (this.myGroupForm.value.share >= 25) {
      this.step = 10;
    } else {
      this.step = 5;
    }
}
```

This is behaving incorrectly.
When Reaching 25 the step value is 10 as expected but the next input value is 30 instead of 35.

Comment: Try `[step]="step"`.

Comment: Hi, I tried this and still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove `min="10"`, it will work.

And if you change `min="10"` to `min="9"`, the input value will be **9**, **19**, **29**.

Therefore, it looks like by defining `min="10"`, browser will make sure the input value can be decreased to 10, so it will increase from 25 to 30 so it can be decreased to 10 if you keep clicking decrease button.

So you should play around `min` attribute.

Hope it helps!

Comment: My pleasure, if my answer helped, would you mind to give it vote?

Answer (score 0):

Use [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-property) to set the `step` property of the `input` element. Replace `step="{{this.step}}"` with `[step]="step"`. So your input element would look like

```
<input [step]="step" type="number" min="10" formControlName="share" (change)="computeStep()">
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodel-form-edhsvn)

Comment: Hi, I tried this and still didn't work. Even with the example you provided it have the same behavior that mine. Can this be related to browser ?  Also i tried to replace 10 by 15 in the example and it works fine.